# How can I see values saved in CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-environments

So I was able to save data in the dashboard, but I'm only able to see the keys in Cloudkit's dashboard.  How do I actually see the values for the keys?

[image]

Here is my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the CloudKit Dashboard, click Records in the menu. In Records, make sure "Loads From:" is set to "Public Database." Press the "Query Records" button and it should load any records that have been saved to the public database.